# RoR : Params object modified in 1 controller does not propagates to the chained controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am modifying params object in my application_controller which handles all the routes coming with root . I have multiple controllers that chain behind the application_controller .

I modified the params object in the application_controller but i get the original params object in the subsequent controllers .

Note: After modification in the application controller i printed out the params ,it got modified there. But when i printed out the same in the subsequent controllers it was back in the original state .

**Application Controller** (Application Controller is in a core Engine which is the first controller that gets hit by the request)

```
before_action :handle_params
def handle_params
      param =  nil
      #Identify method from request object
      method = request.method #Come from request.method
      if method == "GET"
        param = JSON.parse(URI.unescape(params["body"]))
        params[:header] = param[:header]
        params[:data] = param[:data]
      else
        params = params["body"]
      end
    end
```

In my **Common Engine** i have this controller **LoaderController** that gets called after the application_controller.

```
require_dependency "core/application_controller"

module Common
  class API::LoaderController < Core::ApplicationController
    def fetch
        pp params      
        responder FetchLoader.call(@context,params)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please post your applicable code.

Comment: @engineersmnky Added the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
self.params = self.params["body"]
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks man this worked for me . Quite Simple. Have to brush up my ruby i guess :D